# Select single dummy row in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to do something like this in entity framework.

```sql
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log Where LogTypeId =1) as Log1, 
           (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Log Where LogTypeId =2) as Log2
```

Note the lack of from. In essence, I just want to select a single row that contains aggregation of the Log table. I tried something like this.

```
(from x in ctx.Logs
select new {
Log1 = ctx.Logs.Count((x) => x.LogTypeId == 1),
Log2 = ctx.Logs.Count((x) => x.LogTypeId == 2)
}).First();
```

However, this returns a null if `ctx.Logs` doesn't contain any row (new system, or recently archived). While it's not that difficult check for a null return and simply create a blank entry, I want to know if there's a way to handle it so I don't have to do "If null create a blank aggregate with all field set to 0" everywhere I want to create this query (since I will have several similar style of select in multiple places).

I also want to avoid having to do multiple select, to prevent multiple round trips to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, feel a bit silly and figured out that I can use `DefaultIfEmpty`.

```
(from x in ctx.Logs.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
Log1 = ctx.Logs.Count((x) => x.LogTypeId == 1),
Log2 = ctx.Logs.Count((x) => x.LogTypeId == 2)
}).First();
```

Comment: In fact you can use `(from x in ctx.AnyTable.Where(_ => false).DefaultIfEmpty() select ...`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid null value you need to use one on the null handling function:

!.nvl

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

2.nvl2

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm

3.coalesce

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617

Usage:
nvl(yourcolumn,0)
try like this in your code or google for these functions i hope you get some help from my side.

Comment: I suspect the OP uses SqlServer, as seen by the lack of "FROM dual"

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question was not about dealing with null in sql query. But dealing with null that entity framework returns when selecting against an empty collection when I just want to return a single row containing aggregate of the table.